# permission on a user I added locally

Tags: permissions, users, home

I added a user to my Mint (Ubuntu) Desktop so that he could ftp files that I can share – I am peter he is john, so we have `/home/peter` and `/home/john`.
I want to have full permissions on his home share, so I can copy files to and from the shared drive but not give him access to my home directory.

I assumed that I could add myself to the john group would be enough (no)
I have tried various options with no success (Brute force I can `sudo cp` to my home directory then change ownership)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add both users to a common group, then give that group full access to the shared folder.

Some systems have a `users` group for this purpose, so:

```
$ sudo install -d -m 770 -g users /var/ftp/pub/shared
```

That creates a folder underneath the standard location for the FTP daemon's `/pub` directory that any member of group `users` can write to.

(Your FTP setup might have a different parent path. I haven't actually tried this on Mint to check it. Check your FTP daemon's configuration.)

Then you just need to add both `peter` and `john` to that `users` group:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G users peter
$ sudo usermod -a -G users john
```